# Autoscale Policy data in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Autoscale policies using Java client. 
How can I get "Resource Use" information in trigger data? (please refer to attached png file)
This is my code getting Watch data, but it always returns null.

```
    private void getPolicies(){

        Group.Service groupSrv = Group.service(client, 1046365L);

        List<Policy> pList = groupSrv.getPolicies();

        for(Policy po : pList){
            System.out.println("policy name : " + po.getName());
            System.out.println("Cooldown : " + po.getCooldown()); // /60/60/24
            List<ResourceUse> resourceList = po.asService(client).getResourceUseTriggers();

            for(ResourceUse rsc : resourceList){
                System.out.println("rsc id : " + rsc.getId());

                List<Watch> watList = rsc.getWatches();

                for(Watch wat:watList){
                    System.out.println("watch Id : " + wat.getId());
                    System.out.println("watch : " + wat.getMetric());
                }

            }
}
```

[image: policy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is retrieved, but it seems it is not mapped properly to the Softlayer java client objects. Try the code below it will print the information.

I suggest you to try the latest version of the Softlayer Java client, if the issue is still reproducible,  submit an issue in the Softlayer Java client GitHub project.

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Group;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Policy;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.policy.Trigger;

public class TriggersAutoScale {

private static String user = "set me";

    private static String apiKey = "set me";

    private static ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getTriggerWatch();

    }

    public static void getTriggerWatch() {
        Group.Service groupSrv = Group.service(client, 1046365L);

        String triggerMask = "mask[id, name, status[name, keyName], suspendedFlag, "
                + "cooldown, regionalGroupId, minimumMemberCount, maximumMemberCount, "
                + "balancedTerminationFlag ,policies[id,cooldown,name,scaleActions[id,type[id,keyName,name],amount,scaleType],"
                + "triggers[id,type],triggers(SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_OneTime)[date],triggers(SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_Repeating)[schedule],"
                + "triggers(SoftLayer_Scale_Policy_Trigger_ResourceUse)[watches[id,algorithm,metric,operator,period,value]]],"
                + "virtualGuestMemberCount]";

        groupSrv.setMask(triggerMask);
        List<Policy> pList = groupSrv.getObject().getPolicies();
        for (Policy policy : pList) {
            System.out.println (policy.getResourceUseTriggers().size());
            for (Trigger trigger : policy.getTriggers()) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                System.out.println(gson.toJson(trigger));
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The latest client has the same issue. I think I'd better retrieve the data using gson. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The object Mask that I gave you in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305210/detail-information-for-auto-scale-in-sl) returns all the information that you need. But as I told you the portal displays information understandable for the customers and that information cannot be got using the API.

for example for an auto scale group with this value displayed in Resource Use:

***"If my CPU Percentage is greater than 80 for 30 Minute(s)"***

I got this in my API response:

```
            "triggers": [
                {
                    "id": 145903,
                    "type": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "keyName": "RESOURCE_USE",
                        "name": "Resource Use"
                    },
                    "watches": [
                        {
                            "algorithm": "EWMA",
                            "id": 120803,
                            "metric": "host.cpu.percent",
                            "operator": ">",
                            "period": 1800,
                            "value": "80"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

the portal parses that inforamtion like this:

- "algorithm": "EWMA" -> If my
- "metric": "host.cpu.percent" -> CPU Percentage
- "operator": ">"  -> is greater than
- "value": "80"  -> 80
- "period": 1800 ->  for 30 Minute(s)

So if you want to display the same data as the portal, you need to know all the cases about how the portal parses that information.

Regards

Comment: I see.. Thank you. I tried to get watch data using the mask, but it didn't work. please check my java code above.